# Duplicate API is getting created in WSO2 API Manager Publisher

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, publisher

I've published an API named as "DocumentAPI", after publishing I can find two API's with the name "DocumentAPI" in publisher. Can find only one API with name "DocumentAPI" in store. Tried deleting, recreating and republishing the API and also restarted my server.

1. Two gateways(internal(MZ) and external(DMZ)) are there in the current environment which means some the APIs are specific to internal and some are specific to external and some are published to both the gateways(cuurent problematic API is published to both the gateways)
2. There is no synchronize method setup between these two nodes.
3. We are on APIM-2.6.0
4. There is no duplicate entries in AM_API, REG_PATH tables with repect to problematic API. Only in publisher UI we are seeing two APIs with same name,version & conetxt and when I modify any one API the change immediately relfecting into other API as well. In store only one API it is showing and when I test this API through Postman subsequent calls are getting failed.

Note: Publishing in fully distributed environment.

Answer (score 2):

- Are you using APIM wum updated pack or vanilla pack? If it is wum, what is the wum level(AM_HOME/updates/wum)?
- Did you try to recreate a new API instead of that "DocumentAPI" name (with a different name) and did you see the same issue for this when publishing to both GW nodes?
- In APIM 2.6.0 we have seen a similar issue if we have created an API with uppercase (eg: AbcAPi) and published it. Then remove it and try to recreate the api with the same name but lowercase (eg: abcApi) and publish it. Then we can see two API in the publisher portal but not in Store UI. And AM Table has one record. But in the registry has two paths (as you have seen).
  eg:

  1. /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/provider/admin/AbcAPi
  2. /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/provider/admin/abcApi
     One path for that old api name and another path for the new API. Since currently, we have fixed this, and that fix is available in the latest wum updated pack of the APIM 2.6.0. Therefore did you notice such differences in both reg paths (select * from REG_PATH where REG_PATH_VALUE).
     If yes, it has fixed in the latest wum of APIM 2.6.0. The reason here is when removing API, it remains some metadata of old API and when recreating registry keep both paths.

Answer (score 1):

When creating an API in wso2 APIM, it doesn't allow to create two APIs with the same name, context and version (name, context and version should unique). 
As per the provided mentioned details, we hope that both APIs in the publisher node has the same name, context and version.

1. In your distributed set up how many GWs are available(one or many)?
2. If has multiple GW nodes, are you using any deployment artefact syncronize method like NFS?
3. What is the APIM version
4. Are you noticing two records for the above API in the AM database(AM_API table)?

Comment: added required information in problem statement, please have a look!

Comment: - Are you using APIM wum updated pack or vanilla pack? If it is wum, what is the wum level(<AM_HOME>/updates/wum)?
- Did you try to recreate a new API instead of that "DocumentAPI" name (with a different name) and did you see the same issue for this when publishing to both GW nodes?